# How to declare a reciever inside a service in the manifest?

Tags: java, android

I have a receiver inside a service. How do i declare that receiver in the manifest? I need the receiver as i have a scheduled alarm. How i have declared a receiver in the service? code is below. is the logic/syntax correct? The code in the receiver is only executing once. why? what could be the issue

```
package com.todaysfuture.dynpin;


/**
* Created by rishabh on 14/2/16.
*/
public class MyService  extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    //does some stuff


    final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            {
                //does some stuff
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

}
@Nullable
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: don't keep such confusing names. Why have you named your service class as a receiver

Comment: Do not code blindly. Have a understanding of naming convention, calss/method/variable scope etc. Here BroadcastReceiver's scope is within the method. You need reference of the receiver to unregister once task is completed.

Comment: hey. changed it over here

Comment: Is the service kept alive indefinitely? Perhaps the **onReceive** is called only once, because the service terminates?

Answer (score 0):

I will put here an example of what you asked.
The example is listen to Screen on/off.
Hope that will help you.

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            boolean res;
            if (action.equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {
                res = true;
            } else if (action.equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF")) {
                res = true;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Activity that start the service:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.test.myapplication"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: umm. This is what i have done. how is this answer different from what ive done?

Comment: You didn't declared on 'filter' in you service onCreate.

Comment: but i dont need any filter.

Comment: Did you declare about the service in the manifest?                                 <service android:enabled="true" android:name="Your service" />